# Why texture lines on meshes get choppy when exceeding a distance from the point of view?

Tags: webgl, webgl2

Example of lines getting choppy with distance
[image: Example of lines getting choppy with distance].

I've been trying to render cubes with their edges colored by playing around with the uv coordinates (no texture image). The end result looks choppy when somewhat far, I've seen enough webgl demos to know this can be avoided but can't figure out how.

I thought it might have something to do with precision so I tried to increase the precision of the shaders and/or reduce the near/far planes with no success.